# Access scala's case class from java with optional parameters

Tags: java, scala, case-class

I have a case class having an optional parameter. When the parameter is not defined it should be set to some default. 
Eg:

```
case class Foo(bar: Option[Int] = Some(100))
```

The problem arises when I try to access this case class from Java:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(Option.empty())
```

It doesn't assign the default value `100` to variable `bar`

Comment: You could do that from scala too, what would be the point of having an optional default parameter otherwise? Java does not support default parameters so you would have to do this in another way.

Comment: Can you suggest another way?

Comment: The standard way in java would be method overloading, not sure how to do that in scala though

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use apply() method to get an instace of the class with default parameters in the following way:

```
object Foo{
  def getDefault: Foo = new Foo
}
```

Which can be used like this in Java:

```
Foo.getDefault()
```

or if you have more than one default parameters then you will have to use the builder pattern like  this:

```
case class Foo(a: Int = 1, b: Option[Int] = None, c: String = "Hello")

object Foo{
  class Builder{
    var a = 1
    var b = None
    var c = "Hello"
    def withA(x: Int) = {a = x; this}
    def withB(x: Some) = {b = x; this}
    def withC(x: String) = {c = x; this}
    def build = Foo(a,b,c)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
case class Foo(bar: Option[Int]) {
  def this() = this(Some(100))
}
```

If you run it in a scala worksheet with:

```
object Foo{
  val a = new Foo()                         //> a  : week3.Foo = Foo(Some(100))
}
```

Hope this helps